# Insert vector of column names into glm

Tags: r, glm

I would like to construct a glm using a dataframe which has a large amount of coefficients. Instead of manually typing each column name, is it possible to put a vector of the column names instead?

Suppose my dataframe contains a column for each letter in the alphabet, I would like to do something like:

```
alphabet <- c("A", "B", "C", ... , "Z")
model <- glm(y ~ alphabet, data= dataframe)
```

instead of having to do:

```
model <- glm(y ~ A + B + C + ... + Z, data = dataframe)
```

when attempting to construct this linear model using a vector I get this error, which makes sense because the alphabet vector is only the length of the columns

> variable lengths differ (found for 'alphabet')

Answer (score 4):

We could use `reformulate` to create the formula

```
model <- glm(reformulate(alphabet, response = "y"), data = dataframe)
```

-testing

```
> alphabet <- LETTERS
> reformulate(alphabet, response = "y")
y ~ A + B + C + D + E + F + G + H + I + J + K + L + M + N + O + 
    P + Q + R + S + T + U + V + W + X + Y + Z
```

---

as the formula with `y ~ alphabet`, literally creates

```
> y ~ alphabet
y ~ alphabet
```

instead of evaluating the contents in the object

---

Or may need `paste/sprintf`

```
paste("y~ ", paste(alphabet, collapse = "+"))
[1] "y~  A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+O+P+Q+R+S+T+U+V+W+X+Y+Z"
```